# Removing item from Realm and RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview, realm

Here is how I try to remove item from realm and recylerview:

```
public void deleteHistoryTerm(int position){
        mRealm.beginTransaction();
        mResults.get(position).deleteFromRealm();
        mRealm.commitTransaction();
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
```

However, instead of removed item, recylerView displays an empty holder for that item and it goes away when you tap on it. What might be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. I should be removing specific items as following:

```
    mResults.deleteFromRealm(position);
```